# Eclipse IDE on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, bigbluebutton

I installed BigBlueButton on ubuntu server 14.04, and it's working.
Now, i want to create a web app, using spring, where I have to integrate BigBlueButton.

Usually, I use eclipse on windows, but, now, i don't have an idea what should I do.
Do I have to use eclipse on ubuntu ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean if you have to use use Eclipse? You don't HAVE to use Eclipse.

Comment: I want to use eclipse, the question is should i use it on ubuntu or windows ?

Comment: If your question is whether you can use Eclipse on Ubuntu, then the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Okay
Since I am using BigBlueButton on ubuntu, I guess it will be much easier to use eclipse on ubuntu too.
so when I want to integrate BBB with my app it will be possible

Comment: You can download Eclipse for Linux: https://eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux

Comment: Thank you for your answers
I have one more question, the use of eclipse on linux, is same as windows? I mean there are not problems related to the OS ?

Comment: It is pretty much the same.

Comment: Okay, great
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, but it sounds like you might like to.

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not do your development on the same server as where you host the runtime.  If you are comfortable doing development on a Windows machine, do that, and create a .war file to deploy to the Ubuntu server.